# Can you identify the set? Maybe a crane?

Tags: set-identification

We obtained this as part of a bulk lot.  Please help me figure out which set it is from.  A Web search found many cranes, but not like this one. Could be a MOC ;-)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE  This looks like quite a contraption.  Would how you got this help us figure out who might have been the builder?

Comment: Is this LEGO? I can't tell from the picture... does it say *LEGO* on the studs?

Comment: All the studs are carefully watered to disguise any logos on them :-(

Comment: @uli,@jknappen,it says Lego on plate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the pieces in the photo is looks like the remains of set# 4957 Ferris Wheel.

[image]

They had apparently built one of the secondary/alternative models from the set.

(Building instructions here: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=4957)

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I've got motor with it too and some other parts from set picture, looks like it!

Comment: Appreciate the feedback :) That's a great score in a bulk buy!